# Component missing classes when I run 'npm run build', 'npm run start' but others can't reproduce the error

Tags: node.js, npm, material-ui, next.js

[Here's the repo](https://github.com/TidyIQ/input_label_issue).

It's simply [the example provide by Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs-with-typescript) with an extra input component in `pages/index.tsx`

When I run `npm run build` `npm run start` on either my local machine or my VPS, the outlined input component appears like this:

[image: What I see]

The label is appearing above the input, whereas it should be appearing inside it. The reason for this is because it's missing essential classes. Specifically, it's missing this class which is responsible for displaying the label in the correct location:

```
.MuiInputLabel-formControl {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(0, 24px) scale(1);
}
```

I thought this was an issue with Material-UI so I [created an issue in their repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16013), however it appears nobody else can reproduce this error when they follow the exact same steps. Here's what they see:

[image: What others see]

I can only get it to work if I:

- run it in dev mode (`npm run dev`)
- add the component in `pages/_app.tsx` outside the `<Component>` component
- deploy it to Now.sh which requires a serveless config in `next.config.js`

I really don't understand what the issue is. The only other package I have installed on my VPS and local machine is `npm@6.9.0` so it doesn't seem like anything external to the app is causing the issue.

I have deleted the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and reinstalled everything, and I've deleted the `.next` folder and run `npm run build` again to rebuild it, however the issue still appears. I've also tried running the app in different browsers and also in incognito mode. Nothing fixes it.

What else could possibly be causing this issue? I'm completely stuck and can't find any other similar issues that could help explain it.

EDIT: I know how to hack-fix this issue by adding in those class attributes directly into the component itself. I'm looking for an explanation as to what could be causing this issue in the first place so I don't need to use a hack to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Next.js 8.1.0 instead use 8.1.1-canary.51 (from 1 to 51 the latest being 51)
here is the [issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7167)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem that seems similar to yours, when tried to make a production build of my app, that uses material-ui, the styles were all messed up and out of place. I manage to solve by adding a [JSS Provider](https://cssinjs.org/):

```
import JssProvider from "react-jss/lib/JssProvider";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    <JssProvider>
      *the rest of your material-ui components*
    </JssProvider>
  }
}
```

Have you tried something like this?